# Fi-Ware cygnus configuration

Tags: bigdata, configuration-files, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to configure the file cygnus.conf, but, I don't know the FQDM/IP of the Namenodes, hive sever and CKAN API endpoint.
I was search in the catalogue and forge, and I can't see anything about that.

thank you, and the best reggarts.

Answer (score 0):

For the Namenode and the Hive server just use the same endpoint you used to setup your Cosmos account: `http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org`. Regarding CKAN, I'm not sure there is a public CKAN instance running in FI-LAB. Let me check it.